# Change certain values in a list to integers? Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created this dictionary from a file. It has a key with a list of values. The elements in the list are all strings. I want to convert the elements at the indices 1 through 3 to integers.

Here is one key:value that I have in my dictionary.

```
{'Youngstown': ['OH', '4110', '8065', '115436'].....}
```

I want to leave the 'OH' as a string and convert all the other elements to integers.

Like this:

```
{'Youngstown': ['OH', 4110, 8065, 115436].....}
```

This is the code that I have so far.

```
d3 = {}
for k,v in d2.items():
    for i in v:
        for v in range(1,3):
            d3[k] = int(v)

print(d3)
```

However, this just gives the following result:

```
{'Youngstown': 2, ...}
```

This is in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change in a list in place, you can assign to a slice of the list. This makes a readable simple loop:

```
d3 = {
    'Youngstown': ['OH', '4110', '8065', '115436'],
    'Anchorage': ['AK', '5432', '1232', '350492']
}

for l in d3.values():
    l[1:] = map(int, l[1:])
```

After this, `d3` will look like:

```
{'Youngstown': ['OH', 4110, 8065, 115436],
 'Anchorage': ['AK', 5432, 1232, 350492]}
```

If there are elements beyond index 3 that you don't want to touch, you can define the final bound of the slice:

```
l[1:4] = map(int, l[1:4])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are overwriting the value of `d3[k]` each time through your inner `for` loop (which is also overwriting the `v` value incorrectly). You need to set up `d3[k]` as a list, and then append the `int` values to it. For example:

```py
for k, v in d2.items():
    d3[k] = [v[0]]
    for i in range(1, 4):
        d3[k].append(int(v[i]))
```

You could also consider using [`str.isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) to check the values and only convert when that is true. For example:

```py
for k, v in d2.items():
    d3[k] = [int(i) if i.isnumeric() else i for i in v]
```

That could then be wrapped into a nested comprehension:

```py
d3 = { k : [int(i) if i.isnumeric() else i for i in v] for k, v in d2.items() }
```

Comment: `str.isnumeric()` is kind of evil. For example, this works `assert "¼".isnumeric()`. Much better to just do a try catch around `int`.

Comment: @flakes You're right, but for the kind of sample data OP has posted it will work fine. But feel free to upvote dawg's answer which takes that approach.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
di={'Youngstown': ['OH', '4110', '8065', '115436'],'Columbus':['OH','1','2','3']}
```

You can write a little function that uses `try / except` to convert the ints if it is possible to do so:

```
def conv(e):
    try:
        return int(e)
    except ValueError:
        return e 
    
di={k:[conv(e) for e in v] for k,v in di.items()}

>>> di
{'Youngstown': ['OH', 4110, 8065, 115436], 'Columbus': ['OH', 1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
d3 = {}
for k,v in d2.items():
    d3[k] = [v[0]] + [int(n) for n in v[1:]]
```

For each element of the dictionary, it constructs a new list, copying the first element unchanged and applying `int()` to the remaining elements.  It then stores the result in the new `dict`.

Example:  With the following value for `d2`:

```
d2 = {'Youngstown': ['OH', '4110', '8065', '115436'],
      'foo': ['x', '10', '20', '30']}
```

it produces the following for `d3`:

```
{'Youngstown': ['OH', 4110, 8065, 115436], 'foo': ['x', 10, 20, 30]}
```